# search value in inner array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get data set from DB like

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [picID] => 175
        [owner] => xxx@xxx.com
        [likedname] => test name
        [likedUriTN] => g1.jpg
        [date] => 2013-05-11 09:16:17
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [picID] => 179
        [owner] => xxx@xxx
        [likedname] => Paul
        [likedUriTN] => g2.jpg
        [date] => 2013-05-11 09:04:58
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [picID] => 173
        [owner] => xxx@xxx
        [likedname] => Joseph
        [likedUriTN] => j.jpg
        [date] => 2013-05-09 19:44:58
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [picID] => 175
        [owner] => xxx@xxx
        [likedname] => David
        [likedUriTN] => g1.jpg
        [date] => 2013-05-07 14:56:26
    )
)
```

here is my code,

```
if ($result){
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = array('picID'=>$r['picID'], 
                        'owner'=>$r['owner'],
                        'likedname'=>$r['likedname'],
                        'likedUriTN'=>$r['likedUriTN'],
                        'date'=>$r['date']);    
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

but, I want to group by picID and just add likedname in the array

here is my result from what I want

```
[{
    "picID" : "175",
    "owner" : "xxx@xxx",
    **"likedname" : [{
        "0" : "test name",
        "1" : David
    }],
    "date" : "2013-05-11 09:16:17"
}, {
    "picID" : "179",
    ...
}]
```

I searched php about array, but I have no clue yet.

---

Here is the solution.

I modified with antoox's advice. Thanks antoox.

```
    $rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (array_key_exists($r['picID'], $rows)) {
        $rows[$r['picID']]['likedname'][] = $r['likedname'];
    }
    else {
        $rows[$r['picID']] = array( 'picID'=>$r['picID'], 
                                    'owner'=>$r['owner'],
                                    'likedname'=>array($r['likedname']),
                                    'likedUriTN'=>$r['likedUriTN'],
                                    'date'=>$r['date']);   
    }
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this:

```
if($result){
  $rows = array();
  $likedEmail = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (isset($rows[$r['picId']])) {
        $rows[$r['picId']]['likedname'][] = $r['likedname'];
    }
    else {
        $rows[$r['picId']] = array(
            'picID'=>$r['picID'], 
            'owner'=>$r['owner'],
            'likedname'=>array($r['likedname']),
            'likedUriTN'=>$r['likedUriTN'],
            'date'=>$r['date']
        );    
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

You store your array with *picId* as key to ensure the same *picId* is not inserted twice.